# DECLARE....CONDITION FOR not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying the following statement I took from the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-condition.html) on my database

```
DECLARE no_such_table CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42S02';
```

but I continue to get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE no_such_table CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42S02'' at line 1
```

What is that? Why can't I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DECLARE` statement can only be used inside the `BEGIN ... END` (= stored procedures, functions, triggers).

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html